# How to stop Flux buffered writes consistently?

Tags: project-reactor

I have an event stream as input, want to do a series of transformations on them, then buffer them up into a List, and finally perform a batched write in another system. Once the input stream has been drained I want to manually stop this process which needs to flush the remaining buffer into a write. What is the best way to get this to work consistently?

Example:

```
Flux.from(<source>)
    .map(<some transform>)
    .buffer(4096)
    .subscribe(<batched writer that takes a List>)
```

With the above, if I cancel the batched writer subscription I will lose whatever is pending in the buffer. Is there any way I can "complete" the original source, thus causing a flush/drain in the whole pipeline, to ensure no events gets lost?

Comment: any way you could use the `onComplete` signal to express that the input stream has been drained, rather than `cancel`? onComplete will propagate downstream to the `buffer` operator which will cause it to flush its currently accumulated data.

Comment: That's definitely what I want to do. But how to trigger it? I don't control the source or transform code. Can I insert something after the .from() that would do a cancel on the source, and then a complete downstream? That would semantically be what I want to achieve.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of options, such as putting in a .publish() call directly after from() and then doing connect()/dispose(), but that won't drain the buffer, just ignore it. Only working solution so far is to do the buffering in the final subscriber, so I can flush it manually in hookFinally. But that kind of misses the point of having the library do the buffering for me.

Comment: What you want to do is basically highly dependent on the source, and without control over it or guarantee that it maps you idea of "once the input stream has been drained" to an onComplete event, I don't see much options

Comment: Not sure I understand. The source just keeps sending events, but I as a human controlling this process can decide to stop the flow, and in such a case I want to drain the events that are still in the queue. A Processor after the source that calls cancel on the source subscription, and calls onComplete to downstream subscriptions, would seem to do it. I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this correctly in Flux. It seems straightforward, but isn't.